# Adding .php extension to one plugin page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm searching for a solution to add .php extension to the page of my wordpress plugin.

I already found similar posts but none of them was about adding the .php extension to only on page generated by a plugin.

I already tried to work with the `global $wp_rewrite;` but it would apply the .php extension to all pages.

All I want is simply something like that:

`www.mydomain.com/myfile` => `www.mydomain.com/myfile.php` but **only for this one particular page.**

**Update**:
The file `myfile.php` doesn't exist. It's the permalink of a wp page. I basically want to add .php to the permalink of one page (only this one page). I know it's possible to change the permalink of an page, but wp would not let me add `.php` to the permalink. It automatically changes it to `-php` (it doesn't accept the dot).

Comment: Is this for a plugin that you want to use on multiple sites or just one single site? If the latter, just map it at the server level, such .htaccess if you are Apache

Comment: That would work if the `myfile.php` existed. But the file doesn't exist. It's the wp permalink of the page. I basically want to add .php to the permalink of this page (only this page).

Comment: It doesn’t have to exist, just do a rewrite. The reverse of this was a very common thing in the pre-CMS (before we mapped everything to index.php) era where we’d map URLs without an extension one-to-one to a file with the exact same path plus an extension such as .php or .asp

Comment: Shouldn't this work out or am I doing something wrong ? 

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /myfile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myfile.php [L]`. 

The requested URI is `www.mydomain.com/myfile` but it doesn't work

Comment: Please, don't add answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to change the link format for all pages via wp_rewrite. You can add rewrite_rule for a specific page without changing the format for the entire Post Type.

```
    add_rewrite_rule(
      '^myfile.php',
      'index.php?page_id=1234',
      'top'
  );
```

1234 = your page $post_id

Next, we change permalink generation for our page

```
add_filter( 'page_link', 'filter_function_myfile_link', 10, 3 );
function filter_function_myfile_link( $link, $post_id, $sample ){

if ( $post_id == 1234  ) {
$link = home_url('/myfile.php', 'https');
}

    return $link;
}
```

Comment: Hi, your tipp was quite helpful but couldn't solve my problem... 
The function `filter_function_myfile_link` leads to the site with correct extension (`www.mydomain.com/myfile.php`) which then shows a `The page could not be found` exception.

Comment: You need to reload rewrite rules, enable/disable it at admin

Comment: Also you need add add_rewrite_rule to functions.php, not only filter_function_myfile_link